# Request Permission Dialog doesn't show up in Canvas

Tags: asp.net, facebook, oauth-2.0

The Auth class I posted below used to work before. But now, I can't see the permission dialog in facebook app canvas page. (apps.facebook.com/apppage) Those users who were not authorized their facebook accounts before are seeing an empty white page.

But it works fine on my page (www.mypage.com) Are there any new security updates I'm missing? How can I fix this situation?

```
               oAuth.AccessTokenGet(Request["code"]);
                if (oAuth.Token.Length > 0)
                {


                    //We now have the credentials, so we can start making API calls
                    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=" + oAuth.Token;
                    string json = oAuth.WebRequest(oAuthFacebook.Method.GET, url, String.Empty);

                    var facebookClient = new FacebookClient(oAuth.Token);
                    dynamic me = facebookClient.Get("me");
                    string email = me.email;
...
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.Specialized;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Web;

    namespace Web.Facebook
    {
        public class oAuthFacebook
        {
            public enum Method
            {
                GET,
                POST
            };


            public const string AUTHORIZE =
                "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize";
            public const string ACCESS_TOKEN =
                "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
            public string CALLBACK_URL =
                System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CALLBACK_URL"];
            //"/";

            private string _consumerKey = "";
            private string _consumerSecret = "";
            private string _token = "";
            private string _scope =
                System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SCOPE"];

            #region Properties

            public string ConsumerKey
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_consumerKey.Length == 0)
                    {
                        _consumerKey =
                            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CONSUMER_KEY"];
                    }
                    return _consumerKey;
                }
                set
                {
                    _consumerKey = value;
                }
            }

            public string ConsumerSecret
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_consumerSecret.Length == 0)
                    {
                        _consumerSecret =
                            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CONSUMER_SECRET"];
                    }
                    return _consumerSecret;
                }
                set
                {
                    _consumerSecret = value;
                }
            }

            public string Token
            {
                get { return _token; }
                set { _token = value; }
            }
            #endregion

            /// <summary>
            /// Get the link to Facebook's authorization page for this application.
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns>The url with a valid request token, or a null string.</returns>
            public string AuthorizationLinkGet()
            {
                return string.Format("{0}?client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}&scope={3}",
                    AUTHORIZE,
                    this.ConsumerKey,
                    CALLBACK_URL,
                    _scope);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Exchange the Facebook "code" for an access token.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="authToken">The oauth_token or "code" is supplied by Facebook's authorization page following the callback.</param>
            public void AccessTokenGet(string authToken)
            {
                this.Token = authToken;
                string accessTokenUrl = string.Format("{0}?client_id={1}&redirect_uri={2}&client_secret={3}&code={4}",
                    ACCESS_TOKEN,
                    this.ConsumerKey,
                    CALLBACK_URL,
                    this.ConsumerSecret,
                    authToken);
                string response = WebRequest(Method.GET, accessTokenUrl, String.Empty);

                if (response.Length > 0)
                {
                    //Store the returned access_token
                    NameValueCollection qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(response);

                    if (qs["access_token"] != null)
                    {
                        this.Token = qs["access_token"];
                    }
                }
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Web Request Wrapper
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="method">Http Method</param>
            /// <param name="url">Full url to the web resource</param>
            /// <param name="postData">Data to post in querystring format</param>
            /// <returns>The web server response.</returns>
            public string WebRequest(Method method, string url, string postData)
            {
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;
                StreamWriter requestWriter = null;
                string responseData = "";

                webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
                webRequest.Method = method.ToString();
                webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
                webRequest.UserAgent = "[You user agent]";
                webRequest.Timeout = 20000;

                if (method == Method.POST)
                {
                    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                    //POST the data.
                    requestWriter =
                        new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());

                    try
                    {
                        requestWriter.Write(postData);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        throw;
                    }


                    finally
                    {
                        requestWriter.Close();
                        requestWriter = null;
                    }
                }

                responseData = WebResponseGet(webRequest);
                webRequest = null;
                return responseData;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Process the web response.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="webRequest">The request object.</param>
            /// <returns>The response data.</returns>
            public string WebResponseGet(HttpWebRequest webRequest)
            {
                StreamReader responseReader = null;
                string responseData = "";

                try
                {
                    responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                    responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream().Close();
                    responseReader.Close();
                    responseReader = null;
                }

                return responseData;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, since facebook is sending X-Frame-Options: DENY, it's preventing to redirect to another page to get the token. Instead a iframe redirection, I'm getting the access token with JS SDK and redirecting the whole page with the access token I need to the authorized page.

this link below has what is needed to fix. I hope this topic will be useful to some others so I'm not deleting it.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/